# Yui3 interpetation of Yui2

Tags: javascript, yui

How do you migrate this code up to yui3 from yui2?

Yui2:

```
this._suspensionPlanPanel = document.getElementById("rn_"+this.instanceID+"_SuspensionPlanPanel");
var td_list = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName("rn_SuspensionPlan_Target","td",this._suspensionPlanPanel);
this._suspensionPlanTargetTemplate = td_list[0];
```

I've tried turing it into this (Yui3):

```
this._suspensionPlanPanel = this.Y.one(this.baseSelector+"_SuspensionPlanPanel");
var td_list = this.Y.all(this._suspensionPlanPanel.get('id') + ' td.rn_SuspensionPlan_Target');
this._suspensionPlanTargetTemplate = td_list[0];
```

But it keeps coming out as undifined. Console.loging td_list gives me the message:

```
undefined: not bound to any nodes { _query="rn_SuspensionForm_12_Su....rn_SuspensionPlan_Time", _nodes=[0], invoke=function(), more...}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not sure what your code before this sample looks like, but the Y object should not probably not be attached to 'this'.
2. Y.one() takes a CSS selector string, not a plain string ID. If you were calling document.getElementById('foo') before, the YUI3 equivalent is Y.one('#foo').

Be sure to read the YUI Node user guide at http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/node/ for more context and examples. Good luck!